# A question about canonical momentum and arbitrariness for potential in magnetism

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electromagnetism, momentum, classical-electrodynamics

The following question confuses me:

> There exists magnetic field $B_z =- \beta x$ where $x > 0$, and a particle is incident from origin point $(0,0)$ with pisitive charge $q$, mass $m$, and speed $v$ along the $x$ axis. It is very convenient to restrict our discuss in two dimension plane, the $x$-$y$ plane. Find the particle coordinate when its speed is along $y$ axis.

[image]

I want to apply the canonical momentum to find the point.

The canonical momentum, $P=p+qA$, is a conservation quantity when the particle moves. I let the potential $A=(0,- \frac{1}{2} \beta x^2)$ satisfied $B=\nabla \times A$ and the Coulomb's gauge $\nabla \cdot A = 0$, hence the original canonical momentum is $(mv,0)$, and the canonical momentum is always equal to $(mv,0)$.

When the particle is along the y axis, the momentum of the particle is $(0,mv)$, so the potential must be satisfied $qA=P-p=(mv,-mv)$.

Here, I am in trouble. I cannot solve the point where the potential $A$ equals to $(mv,-mv)$, unless I choose another expression for potential.

I am confused about the expression of potential. It should be arbitrary for physics, but here, it is not. If I choose $A=(a \beta xy,b \beta x^2)$ and $2b-a=-1$, there is a freedom degree to set the value of $a$ or $b$, and the point that I have to find is not fixed.

I want to know why here the potential cannot be arbitrarily set its value. Could someone help me?

Comment: Why do you think that the canonical momentum is conserved during the motion?

Comment: The hamiltonion of the system is $H=\frac{P^2}{2m}=\frac{(p+qA)^2}{2m}$ and it must be conserved, so I think that the canonical momentum is also conserved.

Comment: The Hamiltonian involves the **magnitude** of the canonical momentum, so you only expect the magnitude to be conserved, not the individual components.  Unfortunately, even conservation of the magnitude leads to an apparent violation of gauge invariance.  I'm not sure what's going on; if I crack it, I'll write a proper answer.

Comment: The canonical momentum is not gauge invariant.

Answer (score 2):

The canonical momentum is not conserved.
See Landau&Lifshits, vol 2 chap 3.

Let us examine case of homogeneous magnetic field. Then A=xB. We can add constant vector A0 (parallel X axes) without magnetic strength changing. Resulting potential A1=A+A0. Thus canonical momentum equals (mv+qA1,0) at initial position. After quote of circulation the partical velosity is parallel Y axes and canonical momentum equals (qA1,mv)

Comment: Could you explain this in more depth?

Comment: I think the canonical momentum is conserved because the Hamiltonion of the particle $H=P^2/2m$ is conserved where the $P$ is the canonical momentum. Sorry, I don't have the book. Could you tell me more details about it?

Comment: OK. Let us examine case of homogeneous magnetic field. Then A=xB. We can add constant vector A0 (parallel X axes) without magnetic strength changing. Resulting potential A1=A+A0. Thus canonical momentum equals (mv+qA1,0) at initial position. After quote of circulation the partical velosity is parallel Y axes and canonical momentum equals (qA1,mv).

Comment: @ANDREW: could you edit your answer to expand on the stuff in your comment. As it stands I note a couple of people have already flagged it as *not an answer*.

Comment: @qfzklm: OK. Let us examine case of homogeneous magnetic field. Then A=xB. We can add constant vector A0 (parallel X axes) without magnetic strength changing. Resulting potential A1=A+A0. Thus canonical momentum equals (mv+qA1,0) at initial position. After quote of circulation the partical velosity is parallel Y axes and canonical momentum equals (qA1,mv).

Comment: @Hunter: OK. Let us examine case of homogeneous magnetic field. Then A=xB. We can add constant vector A0 (parallel X axes) without magnetic strength changing. Resulting potential A1=A+A0. Thus canonical momentum equals (mv+qA1,0) at initial position. After quote of circulation the partical velosity is parallel Y axes and canonical momentum equals (qA1,mv).

Comment: @ANDREW, please edit your answer so it will reflect your reasoning. As now, it looks like a comment and it can be deleted(I am not voting on deletion, but it makes sense to do so).

Comment: @ANDREW, Thank you very much for your explanation, it is exactly that the canonical momentum is not conserved in the case. But I still have one point that I am not understand. I have written down the hamiltonion before, and I think it is conserved and it will lead to the canonical momentum conserved. So, here, where am I wrong?

Answer (score 1):

You know that $$m\vec a=q\vec v \times \vec B,$$

So in particular, since $\vec B = B\hat z,$ we have $$ma_x=qv_yB,\text{ and } ma_y=-qv_xB. $$

And in our case $B=-\beta x$ so we have $$m\ddot x=-q\dot y\beta x\text{ and } m\ddot y=q\dot x\beta x. $$

You can take the time derivative of the left equation and get $$m\dddot x=-q\ddot y\beta x-q\dot y\beta \dot x,$$ which becomes

$$m\dddot x=-q\left(\frac{q\dot x\beta x}{m}\right)\beta x-q\left(\frac{m\ddot x}{-q\beta x}\right)\beta \dot x.$$

This third order equation needs initial conditions $x(0)=0,$ $\dot x(0)=v,$ and $\ddot x(0)=0$ (why?). And you can then find the time $t=T$ when $\dot x(t=T)=0.$ From that $T$ and the function $x(t)$ you can get $x(T)$ which is half of what you want.

You can make a similar third order equation for $y(t)$ and either solve it and then get $t=T$ where $\dot y(t=T)=\pm v$ (which one?) and confirm the two $T$ are the same ($\dot x^2+\dot y^2$, unlike the canonical momentum, is conserved). And in the end from the $T$ and the function $y(t)$ you can get $y(T)$ which is  the other half of what you want.

Note I didn't use a vector potential, a Lagrangian, a Hamiltonian, or an appeal to QM. And the one use of a conserved quantity, $\dot x^2+\dot y^2,$ was optional.

So what's wrong with what you did? Firstly, canonical momentum is usually not a conserved quantity, it is just the variable needed to make a Legendre transformation from the $Q, \dot Q$ coordinates of the Lagrangian to the $Q,P$ coordinates of the Hamiltonian. If the Lagrangian doesn't depend on a $Q$ then the corresponding $P$ is conserved.  Now, $L(\vec x, \vec v)=-mc^2\sqrt{1-\frac{v^2}{c^2}}+q\vec A\cdot\vec v -q\Phi,$ since

$$\frac {d}{dt}\left(\frac{mv_i}{\sqrt{1-\frac{v^2}{c^2}}}+qA_i\right)=\frac {d}{dt}\left(\frac{\partial L}{\partial v_i}\right)=\frac {d P_i}{dt}$$

and

$$\frac{\partial L}{\partial Q_i}=v_x\frac{\partial A_x}{\partial Q_i}+v_y\frac{\partial A_y}{\partial Q_i}+v_z\frac{\partial A_z}{\partial Q_i}.$$

The right hand side is not zero, so the Euler-Lagrange equations $\frac {d}{dt}\left(\frac{\partial L}{\partial v_i}\right)=\frac{\partial L}{\partial Q_i}$ do not yield that the momentum $P_i=\frac{\partial L}{\partial v_i}$ is conserved and in fact

$$\frac {d P_i}{dt}=\frac{\partial L}{\partial Q_i}=v_x\frac{\partial A_x}{\partial Q_i}+v_y\frac{\partial A_y}{\partial Q_i}+v_z\frac{\partial A_z}{\partial Q_i}.$$

The reason we know that the Lagrangian is $L(\vec x, \vec v)=-mc^2\sqrt{1-\frac{v^2}{c^2}}+q\vec A\cdot\vec v -q\Phi,$ is because the Euler-Lagrange equations $\frac {d}{dt}\left(\frac{\partial L}{\partial v_i}\right)=\frac{\partial L}{\partial Q_i}$ leads to

$$\frac {d}{dt}\left(\frac{mv_i}{\sqrt{1-\frac{v^2}{c^2}}}+qA_i\right)=v_x\frac{\partial A_x}{\partial Q_i}+v_y\frac{\partial A_y}{\partial Q_i}+v_z\frac{\partial A_z}{\partial Q_i}.$$

Which is equivalent to $$\frac {d}{dt}\left(\frac{m\vec v}{\sqrt{1-\frac{v^2}{c^2}}}\right)=q\left(-\frac{\partial \vec A}{\partial t}-\vec \nabla \Phi + \vec v \times \left(\vec \nabla \times \vec A\right)\right).$$

Since other people brought up Hamiltonians, you can get a Hamiltonian as $H(\vec Q,\vec P,t)=\sqrt{(mc^2)^2+(\vec P-q\vec A)^2c^2}+q\Phi$ (which is approximately $mc^2 +(\vec P-q\vec A)^2/2m +q\Phi$ in the nonrelativistic limit). And we can denote $\vec p=\vec P -q\vec A$ as the kinetic momentum. And for people that bring up quantum theory into this, the canonical momentum is what obeys the canonical commutator relationship so since the kinetic momentum is $\vec p=\vec P -q\vec A$ the different components of the kinetic momentum do not commute with each other because of the vector potential term.

Answer (score -1):

I need the Latex environment to correct the answer provided by @Urgje, so forgive me for writing a new answer. As shown by [Hitoshi](http://hitoshi.berkeley.edu/221a/landau.pdf), the commutator between the two components of kinetic momentum is:

$$[P_x,P_y]=i\frac{e\hbar}{c}B_z$$

Let's now show that the kinetic momentum does not commute with the Hamiltonian.

$$[P_x,P^2]=[P_x,(P_x^2+P_y^2)]=[P_x,P_y^2]=[P_x,P_y]P_y+P_y[P_x,P_y]=2i\frac{e\hbar}{c}B_zP_y\neq0$$

Similarly, $P_y$ doesn't commute with the Hamiltonian. Therefore, the kinetic momentum $\vec{P}\equiv(P_x,P_y)$ does not commute with the Hamiltonian $H=\frac{P^2}{2m}$. As a result, the kinetic momentum is not conserved! This is not surprising since in the classical system kinetic momentum is not conserved either. Remember that electrons in the classical system move in circular orbits.

Answer (score -2):

Since $P=p+qA$ commutes with $H={P^2}/2m$, it is a constant of the motion. But this is not true for $p$, so I have the impression that there is some confusion about $P$ and $p$.

Comment: The discussion by @ANDREW shows the canonical momentum is not a conservation. But here, from the hamilonion, it seems that the canonical momentum (maybe the magnitude of the canonical momentum) should be conserved. I am still confused about this point.

Comment: I do not understand the remarks by @Andrew very well. But as long as H=P^2/2m then P commutes with H. Since dP/dt is proportional to the commutator [P,H] it vanishes so P is constant.

Comment: @qfzklm In classical mechanics you need the Poisson bracket to be zero, not the commutator to be zero.  And indeed there does seem to be some confusion between p P.

Comment: It is not true that as long as H=p^2/2m then p commutes with H. H only involves the magnitude of the kinetic momentum p. The two components p_x and p_y of the kinetic momentum do not commute. Try to prove this for yourself. Since p^2=p_x^2+p_y^2, it follows that neither p_x nor p_y commute with p^2, and therefore neither of these components of the kinetic momentum commute with the Hamiltonian. It is also true that the canonical momentum does not commute with the Hamiltonian.

Comment: @Ian I have the impression that your statements are incorrect.

Comment: @Urgje I demonstrate in a new answer why the kinetic momentum P does not commute with Hamiltonian P^2/2m. Please let me know if you still disagree.